Getting 401 error in advance reporting in Magento 2.4
I am getting error as in Image added below.
I have followed all the steps as mentioned in devdoc.
*Troubleshooting
If you get a 404 “Page Not Found” message, verify that your store meets the requirements for Advanced Reporting. Then, follow the instructions to verify that the integration is installed.
Verify that the integration is active

On the Admin sidebar, go to System > Extensions > Integration.
Verify that the Magento Analytics user integration appears in the list and the Status is
Active.
To reestablish the user, click Reauthorize and do the following:

When prompted, click Reauthorize to approve access to the API
resources.
Verify that the list of Integration Tokens for Extensions    is
complete. Then, click Done.


Look for the message that indicates the integration Magento
Analytics user is reauthorized.
Wait overnight or until after the time of your next scheduled
update.*

After following that steps still not able tp see reporting. Please help to fix it.
Magento version : 2.4.6 (Open Source)


Follow this link that might help you to get more idea to resolve this issue https://www.hulkapps.com/blogs/ecommerce-hub/troubleshooting-the-401-error-in-advanced-reporting-in-magento-2-4-6

@Shraddha Patel I have tried the recommendation as in doc but no luck. Still same issue

@Amit Kumar
Hey, have a look at below steps:

Go to phpmyadmin

Search the below shown path
analytics/general/token
See record found or not, if record found than delete that record.

After cron execution, it generates the token and report will be working after 1 hour


Thank You!

I have tried this but still facing the same issue. I have deleted the record and reauthorize as well.
